# Unable to install Keras in my conda environment in Windows 10. Error message: call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node 1>nul 2>&1

Tags: windows, keras, conda, virtual-environment, installation-package

OS: Windows-10

I'm trying to install data science packages in my Conda virtual environment. I've created and worked in such conda environments before and faced no issues at all, even while using Keras. But, this time, I am not even able to understand the cause of this issue.

This is how I created my Conda virtual environment:

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. `cd path_to_my_project_folder`
3. `conda create --prefix ./env numpy keras tensorflow  jupyter notebook flask`
4. `conda activate path_to_my_project_folder/env`

During and after installation of packages I don't see any error messages. But, as soon as I activate my conda environment I get the following error messages, and also, when I check the installed packages, I see all the packages except Keras. As soon as I activate my conda virtual environment I get the following error messages in my  Anaconda Prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>conda activate  C:/Users/Neerva/Documents/SU/SEM5/ibm_ice/tomato_leaf_disease_prediction/env

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>python C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction\env\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>del temp.txt

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>SET "VS_VERSION=15.0"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>SET "VS_MAJOR=15"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>SET "VS_YEAR=2017"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\bin\vcruntime140.dll"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set "CXX=cl.exe"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set "CC=cl.exe"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>set "VSINSTALLDIR="

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -version [15.0,16.0) -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" )

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if not exist "" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" ) )

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if not exist "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" )

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" )

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" )

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\" )

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>IF NOT "" == "" (
set "INCLUDE=;"
 set "LIB=;"
 set "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=;"
)

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>call :GetWin10SdkDir

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>exit /B 0

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>for /F %i in ('dir /ON /B "\include\10.*"') DO (SET WindowsSDKVer=%~i )
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 (echo "Didn't find any windows 10 SDK. I'm not sure if things will work, but let's try..." )  else (echo Windows SDK version found as: "" )
Windows SDK version found as: ""

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>IF "win-64" == "win-64" (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
 set "BITS=64"
)  else (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017"
 set "BITS=32"
)

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>popd

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>IF "" == "" SET "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

C:\Users\Neerva\Documents\SU\SEM5\ibm_ice\tomato_leaf_disease_prediction>exit /B 0
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

An issue which is similar to my own issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13209

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @merv I'm sorry for my mistake. I have read the article shared by you and I have edited my question. Please have a look, and help me out. Also feel free to point out my mistakes, if any. Thank you.